# Javascript - If Conditions Separated by "&&" (Need Advice)

Tags: php, javascript, forms, if-statement, operators

Should be a pretty simple fix needed for this...

I have a registration form that I want to be validated for empty fields and have javascript return a simple pop-up alert if necessary.  Here's the script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var a = document.forms["registration_form"]["school"].value;
        var b = document.forms["registration_form"]["name"].value;
        var c = document.forms["registration_form"]["password"].value;
        var d = document.forms["registration_form"]["field"].value;
        var e = document.forms["registration_form"]["field_location"].value;
        var f = document.forms["registration_form"]["volleyball_campus"].value;
        var g = document.forms["registration_form"]["volleyball_location"].value;
        var h = document.forms["registration_form"]["indoor"].value;
        var i = document.forms["registration_form"]["outdoor_courts"].value;
        var j = document.forms["registration_form"]["blackout"].value;
        var k = document.forms["registration_form"]["blackout_dates"].value;
        if (a == "" || b == "") {
            alert("Please make sure to enter your name and school.");
            return false;
        } else if (c != "pal") {
            alert("Sorry, your password is invalid.");
            return false;
        } else if (d == "no" && e == "") {
            alert("Please make sure to enter where you will play football.");
            return false;
        } else if (f == "no" && g == "") {
            alert("Please make sure to enter where you will play volleyball.");
            return false;
        } else if (h == "no" && i == "0") {
            alert("Please make sure to select how many outdoor volleyball courts you will use.");
            return false;
        } else if (j == "yes" && k == "") {
            alert("Please make sure to enter your blackout dates.");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Everything works fine for variables a, b and c.  However, the else if conditions, beginning with variables d && e, do not seem to execute.  I think I must be doing something wrong with the phrasing, but I can't figure out what it is.

I've set-up my server-side php script to do exactly the same thing and it works without any problems.  You can see it here:

```
//Validate the form:
if ($_POST['school'] == "" || $_POST['name'] == "") {
    echo "Please make sure to enter your name and school.";
} elseif ($_POST['password'] != "pal") {
    echo "Sorry, your password is invalid.";
} elseif ($_POST['field'] == "no" && $_POST['field_location'] == "") {
    echo "Please make sure to enter where you will play football.";
} elseif ($_POST['volleyball_campus'] == "no" && $_POST['volleyball_location'] == "") {
    echo "Please make sure to enter where you will play volleyball.";
} elseif ($_POST['indoor'] == "no" && $_POST['outdoor_courts'] == "0") {
    echo "Please make sure to select how many outdoor volleyball courts you will use.";
} elseif ($_POST['blackout'] == "yes" && $_POST['blackout_dates'] == "") {
    echo "Please make sure to enter your blackout dates.";
} else {
```

This catches everything the way I intended, but the client-side Javascript validation (which I run first only for the more user-friendly appearance) does not seem to work past the first three variables.

I can't for the life of me figure out why.  I've searched all over the internet, but can't quite find the answer I'm looking for.  Any help would be much appreciated!

P.S. The page itself is located at http://www.712jefferson.org/pal/registration.html, if that helps clarify the intended process.

Comment: does d & e have values in them? any console errors?

Comment: How do you know they're going wrong? Do you know for sure what the values of the variables are?

Comment: Who names their variables this way? Sheesh.

Comment: server side validation is not for back-up, it's a must, you can't rely on client side validation, that is just to provide a better UX

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Apologies for the vague variable names.  Not very explanatory, I agree.  I do agree about the server-side validation, but I prefer the look of the pop-ups for ease of use only.  Here's the web URL: 712jefferson.org/pal/registration.html

Answer (score 2):

The alerts will only show if `d` is equal to `no` AND `e` is left empty.  The same applies for `f` and `g`.  This doesn't make sense.  Take this example:

I play `volleyball` but do not play at the campus so I enter `no` in `f`, your logic expects me to put an empty string in `g` where really you want the user to enter the volleyball location.

This should be changed to:

```
else if (f == "no" && g != "") {

}
```

Notice the change from `==` to `!=` this means that `g` is not equal to an empty string.  The same applies to `d` and `e` (You don't want `e` to be empty if `d` is set to "no").

Also validating your password client side is risky, I hope you have server side validation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I actually do intend the statement the way it is written.  Here is the URL to the page for more perspective: 712jefferson.org/pal/registration.html.  Agreed about the risk of client-side password validation.  That is very temporary.

Answer (score 0):

If the subsequent conditions are not evaluating, it is probably because one of the prior conditions have been evaluated and met already, and returned. if you want to confirm that all conditions are being evaluated, you could remove the return statements and add a console.log() message to each condition outputting the true/false state of the condition,

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
else if (registration_form.field[1].checked == true && e == "") {
  alert("Please make sure to enter where you will play football.");
  return false;
  }
```

and make that radio button as any one active

```
<input type="radio" name="field" checked="checked" value="yes">
<input type="radio" name="field" value="no">
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't want to default one of the radio buttons as checked, unless they've already specified that they will indeed have a football team.

Comment: That one is optional if u want u make it otherwise leave